# Unwrapping datatypes in Haskell without extraneous code

Tags: haskell, coding-style

Say I have

```
x = Just 2
```

Is there a way (preferrably a builtin mechanism/function) to use x in a single statement such that if it is a Just, then the 2 is automatically unwrapped and used, and if it is a Nothing, an exception is raised?

That is,

`(f x) + 2 == 4` if `x == Just 2`, and raises an exception if `x == Nothing`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Data.Maybe.fromJust` has been mentioned by other answers already:

```
fromJust :: Maybe a -> a
fromJust Nothing  = error "Maybe.fromJust: Nothing"
fromJust (Just x) = x
```

There's also `maybe` (found in both `Prelude` and `Data.Maybe`):

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
maybe n _ Nothing  = n
maybe _ f (Just x) = f x
```

`fromJust` can be written using `maybe`:

```
fromJust = maybe (error "Maybe.fromJust: Nothing") id
```

As you can see, `maybe` allows you flexibility in handling both cases without requiring pattern matching:

```
\x -> maybe 0 (+ 2) x  -- Nothing -> 0, Just 2 -> 4
```

Similarly, `Prelude` and `Data.Either` have `either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c`:

```
\x -> either (subtract 1) (* 2) x  -- Left 5 -> 4, Right 3 -> 6
```

---

If you define a data type

```
data MyDataType
  = TypeA { foo :: Int, bar :: String }
  | TypeB { foo :: Int,                baz :: () }
  | TypeC {             bar :: String, baz :: () }
```

like this, you end up with partial functions for accessors.

```
foo :: MyDataType -> Int
bar :: MyDataType -> String
baz :: MyDataType -> ()
```

They're called partial functions, as opposed to total functions, because they only return results for a subset of their inputs.

```
foo (TypeA { foo = 15, bar = "hello!" })  -- 15
bar (TypeB { foo = 12345679, baz = () })  -- error
```

Answer (score 12):

For this particular case, `fromJust`.  In general

```
let Just k = x in f k + 2 == 4
```

This trick works with any datatype constructor and is very commonly used with `(:)` for nonempty lists.

Answer (score 10):

[fromJust](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/strict/0.3.2/doc/html/Data-Strict-Maybe.html#v%3AfromJust) should do what you want.

Comment: The needed [package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html) is `import Data.Maybe`.