# Maybe Int type error

Tags: haskell

I'm getting a type error because I'm trying to recursively add a Maybe int int the function rankP seen bellow. Because the return type of rankP is Maybe Int, and the type of rankC is a tuple of Ints, it is telling me I cannot add Int with Maybe Int.

```
type Prog = [Cmd]

data Cmd = LD Int
    | ADD
    | MULT
    | DUP
    | INC
    | SWAP
    | POP Int
    deriving Show       
type Stack = [Int]
type D = Stack -> Maybe Stack
type Rank = Int
type CmdRank = (Int,Int)


rankC :: Cmd -> CmdRank
rankC (LD _) = (0,1)
rankC ADD = (2,1)
rankC MULT = (2,1)
rankC DUP = (1,2)
rankC INC = (1,1)
rankC SWAP = (2,2)
rankC (POP x) = (x,0)


rankP :: Prog -> Maybe Rank
rankP [] = Nothing
rankP [x] = Just (snd(rankC x) - fst(rankC x))
rankP (x:xs) = if ((Just (snd(rankC x) - fst(rankC x)) + rankP xs) < 0) then Nothing
                    else Just (snd(rankC x) - fst(rankC x)) + (rankP xs)
```

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
hw3.hs:43:64:
    Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Maybe Rank'
    In the return type of a call of `rankP'
    In the first argument of `Just', namely `(rankP xs)'
    In the second argument of `(+)', namely `Just (rankP xs)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, and what is your question?

Comment: Where is the error occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to do arithmetic with a `Maybe Rank` when you really need to extract the `Rank` from the `Maybe Rank` before doing any math. One way to do this is directly by hand:

```
rankP (x:xs) = if y == Nothing
               then Nothing
               else let Just y' = y in
                    if snd(rankC x) - fst(rankC x) + y' < 0
                    then Nothing
                    else Just (snd(rankC x) - fst(rankC x) + y')
    where y = rankP xs
```

There are certainly more elegant ways to do this when you begin to understand the monadic properties of `Maybe`. I'm not there yet myself to give much help along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting a slightly different error:

```
No instance for (Num (Maybe Int)) arising from a use of ‘+’
In the first argument of ‘(<)’, namely
  ‘(Just (snd (rankC x) - fst (rankC x)) + rankP xs)’
In the expression:
  ((Just (snd (rankC x) - fst (rankC x)) + rankP xs) < 0)
In the expression:
  if ((Just (snd (rankC x) - fst (rankC x)) + rankP xs) < 0) then
      Nothing
  else
      Just (snd (rankC x) - fst (rankC x)) + (rankP xs)
```

However, note that in

```
(Just (snd(rankC x) - fst(rankC x)) + rankP xs) < 0
```

you're trying to use `+` on two `Maybe Rank` objects, and compare the result with `<` to 0. Neither of these can work.

From your code, it looks like you're trying to "extract" the value of a `Maybe Rank`; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940349/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-maybe-in-haskell) about that.