# How to work with maybe to detect sudoku values

Tags: haskell, sudoku, option-type

I want to form a list of `Bool`s for if values suite a Sudoku format. i.e either `Nothing` or `Just x` where (1 <= `x` <= 9). Here is my code below:

```
import Data.Ix
import Data.Maybe

isSudokuValues :: (Ix a, Num a) => [Maybe a] -> [Bool]
isSudokuValues list = map (maybe True inRange(1, 9).fromJust) list
```

Comment: I think its really clear what the function takes in and what it produces. A List of Maybes and returns a list of booleans. Its well visible on the function signature....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you make two errors:

`maybe` has the following signature:

```
b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

So you should use:

```
map (maybe True $ inRange (1,9)) list
```

the `fromJust` cannot be used, since then `maybe` would work on `a` (instead of `Maybe a`, and furthermore it is one of the tasks of `maybe` simply to allow safe data processing (such that you don't have to worry about whether the value is `Nothing`.

Some Haskell users furthermore consider `fromJust` [to be harmfull](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2100095/67579): there is no guarantee that a value is a `Just`, so even if you manage to let it work with `fromJust`, it will error on `Nothing`, since `fromJust` cannot handle these. *Total programming* is one of the things most Haskell programmers aim at.

**Demo** (with `ghci`):

```
Prelude Data.Maybe Data.Ix> (map (maybe True $ inRange (1,9))) [Just 1, Just 15, Just 0, Nothing]
[True,False,False,True]
Prelude Data.Maybe Data.Ix> :t (map (maybe True $ inRange (1,9)))
(map (maybe True $ inRange (1,9))) :: (Num a, Ix a) => [Maybe a] -> [Bool]
```

Comment: Yeah, just dropping `. fromJust` as also a good solution, since `maybe` already does `fromJust`.

Comment: @EmilVikström: technically `maybe` doesn't use `fromJust` if I recall, but uses the `(Just x)` in the head as you wrote in your answer. `fromJust` is considered to be harmful by some.

Comment: i think this wont work because inRange must have the same type as its range of values. I tried this out separately and it worked...inRange(1, 9) $ fromJust $ Just 2.....and got the result of True

Comment: @HakimMarley: Your comment doesn't make much sense: first you say that you think this won't work, the next statement is that you tried it out and it worked.

Comment: @HakimMarley: I've added a type check, and as you can see, the signature matches with the one you are looking for. This means that `1` and `9` don't *ground* the type to `Integer`, but keep it as generic as possible.

Comment: I was missing out the $ sign but its all up and running....this is a much better solution as its just one line and makes work more readable. Thanks man!!

Answer (score 3):

It is much easier to break out the actual value check to a helper function that works on a single element. That way you can easily see where you unpack the Maybe value

```
isSudokuValues :: (Ix a, Num a) => [Maybe a] -> [Bool]
isSudokuValues =
  let
    isSudokuValue :: (Ix a, Num a) => Maybe a -> Bool
    isSudokuValue Nothing = True
    isSudokuValue (Just x) = inRange (1, 9) x
  in map isSudokuValue
```